# How can I utilize a button to perform an action that is inside of a static class?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a beginner c# student and we have just started working with WinForms. For an assignment we have been given a GUI that we have to create and a few classes with methods to go along with it. I won't put all of the info here because it will be too much. Basically one of the key components of the winform is for the user to be able to type in a txt file name and click the "load" button and have it display the contents of the file. I know how to read from a file and all that.

My problem is that I don't know how I can utilize the Load method that I have since it is in a static class. My instructor has specified in the requirements that it must be a static class which looks like this:

```
public static class DataStore
{
    public static Catalog Load(string filePath)
    {

    }

    public static void Save(Catalog catalog, string filePath)
    {

    }
}
```

Catalog is another class I have but I don't feel it's relevant to my question. What I'm wondering is, how am I supposed to call the Load method in my button click event which looks like this:

```
 private void Load_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 }
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how I'm supposed to link these two things: the method and the click event.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but have you tried `DataStore.Load` ?

Comment: Well, your DataStore has a Load method, so call it. You just need to supply the correct string. `Catalog myCatalog = DataStore.Load("[The Path]");`

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the `Load` method the filepath?

```
private void Load_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // get the file path from the textbox, probably want a validation check to
   // ensure that it's a valid path
   Catalog catalog = DataStore.Load(filePath);
}
```

Comment: When I try to access the DataStore class it doesn't show up. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are the `namespaces` the same?

Comment: Yes they are. I can access Catalog but not DataStore.

Comment: `DataStore` and `Form1` are in the same `namespace`?  I just created a mock project, using the same namespace and was able to find `DataStore`.  If you are using VisualStudio you can Right Click->Quick Actions and Refactorings... (Ctrl+.) on `DataStore` in the `click` method to get more info.

Comment: Ah the issue was that I had a groupbox that had the same name. So when I changed the name of that then my DataStore class showed up in the options. Idk why that would affect it though...

Answer (score 0):

You can call it directly

```
private void Load_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var data = DataStore.Load("filepath");
}
```